# Работа со строкой в С++

Tags: c++

Как можно сделать следующее в С++? Ввожу первое слово, например "Help", затем второе, например "Lost" и чтобы он с заданной части слов уделяй их и потом склеивал их. Например у меня было "HelLo"? Склеивание я знаю как сделать, с помощью "strcat". Поможете как сделать такое?

Comment: Если работа с c-style строками необязательна, то лучше используйте класс [`string`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/ru/string/start).

Comment: спасибо. А можешь маленький пример мне показать? Или же словами просто объяснить? Метод substr я знаю. А склеивание с чем воспроизвести? Strcat подойдет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string::erase
string::append
string::operator+=
string::replace
```

Еще можно [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) посмотреть

Если нужно использовать С-строки, то список функций можно увидеть [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/) или в любом справочнике/учебнике по С или С++

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Comment: По хорошему надо взять первый символ второго и последний первого слова и пока они равны двигаться к концу второго и началу первого. 

Потом оставшееся начало первого и конец второго слов "склеить" (реально strcmp() подойдет). 

Если слова окажутся "зеркальными" друг другу, то результат пустая строка.

IMHO алгоритм такой, а с substr, strstr и т.п. естественная программка не получится.

Comment: думаю ваш вариант сложнее. А чем плох substr??? Мне лично, кажется что с ним будет намного проще.

Comment: @Хэшкод хорошо. Я не знал )

Comment: @navi1893, Вы правы.

Извините, невнимательно прочитал Ваш вопрос. Мой алгоритм для другой задачи. Видимо, без вложенных циклов тут не обойтись.